# How do I pull in new directories when doing SVN update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working on a project from multiple sites.  At site-1 I added a new subdirectory (actually a new "Project" within a Visual Studio "Solution") and Added/checked-in that to SVN (using TortoiseSVN).

At site-2 I did an Update (also Tortoise) on my working directory, but that did not pull in the new subdirectory.  It did pull in new .exe's to a debug folder though, perhaps because that directory already existed??

Using the repro browser, I see the directory and code; and I can create a whole new checkout to a new top level directory.  But why doesn't an Update on the old directory pull in the new folder and files?  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: you assumption is correct: SVN should create this new created folder. It would be helpful to see the full SVN Commands and their cmd-line output. I suspect a wrong URL or a fixed revision (so you never update to a more current revision)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the CORRECT answer but I finally got something to work.

I had been working exclusively with the TortoiseSVN context menu options. You know, right click the directory, select "SVN Update", or Tortoise SVN -> Update to revision... but those were not pulling in the newly added subdirs.

Inspired by @Peter Parker's comment, I decided to play with the command line.  That didn't do anything other than what had been accomplished with the Tortoise context menus, until I, on a whim, tried the command

```
svn update -r HEAD --set-depth infinity
```

It was only with the --set-depth that the new sub dirs showed up.  I chose 'infinity' since that seemed like the biggest hammer.  Maybe one of the other options would have accomplished the same thing with more finesse.

Having found how to make it work on the command line, I see that in the TortoiseSVN -> "Update to revision" dialog, there is an Update Depth.  That was set to "Working copy" (and 'sticky') and probably I needed "Fully recursive" or "Immediate children including folder".

Thanks for the bandwidth.